# WooCommerce tracking variable product views/selects

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce

I'm just working on the tracking of woocommerce variable products with google analytics. Tracking simple products is not a big deal, because every page view is a product. However for me it's pretty interessing to know which product variations users looked at.

I need some similar stats for variable products. Which variable products did the users look at? My products do have quite some variations since one product has about 7 attributes.

I think it shouldn't be to hard to hook into the drop down selects of woocommerce variable products with js and fire on select.

**How would you track the product variation views with google analytics?**

I don't want to mix page views, sales and on the other hand view of product variations too much. I'd rather prefer to track the views of variations through events into a different view (or property). How you get those events into one view and everything else in the default view?

How would you track the parameters to be able to analyse them? My main filter will be product, than I want to filter on different attributes and see how the other attributes cluster on user impressions.

Anyone already has a script for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add event handler for 'found_variation' in JS. That is woocommerce event for selecting variation.

And then use analytics built in function:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(this).on('found_variation', function(event, variation) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Variation', 'Select', variation.variation_id]);
    });
});
```

Haven't tested it but in theory it should work.
And just check variable 'variation' to see what info is available.

Comment: Could have thought of tracking the variation id myself ^^ this makes much more sence than tracking single attribute changes! I really appreciate your code snipped @ViszinisA. works! Gonna Test in production now.